# Automatically unbind event handlers in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to say to JQuery, hey! unbind any event handlers before adding this one, without making an explicit call to unbind?.

Something like

```
$("jq selector").click(function() { ...}, true);
```

Where true means I want to unbind all click handlers set to the element.
I've came across this on various occasions and on some had strange behaviours due not unbinding event handlers first.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `$(selector).unbind("click").click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Why don't you want to call unbind?

Comment: jquery "appends" new handler attachments, not replace them. You have to manually remove those you want removed.

Comment: Look at [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and see if that would solve your problem instead.

Comment: The .one() looks promising but I think the comment from Pointy is in some way what I was looking for. Pointy, can you add it as an answer so I mark it as the correct one?.

Comment: The click event was just used as an example. I used that particular case but the question applies for all events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method

```
$("jq selector").unbind('click');
```

If you want to remove all events associated with an element, Call unbind() with no argument and it will removes all handlers attached to the element(s):

```
$("jq selector").unbind();
```

Comment: I believe the OP was just using 'Click' as an example and wants a generic function to remove any and all bindings without knowing the event. ex. An unbind('all')

Comment: @fbfcn : unbind without parameter will remove all bindings

Comment: Yeah, I was just asking if there was a way to not make an explicit call to ubind before.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).die("click").click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: `die` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, should be `off`

Comment: YES: As of jQuery 1.7, use of .die() (and its complementary method, .live()) is not recommended. Instead, use .off() to remove event handlers bound with .on()

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but I believe the correct would be:

```
$(selector).unbind("click").click(function() { ... });
```

I give the credit of the answer to [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy), who replyed in a comment, but since he didn't add it as an answer I share it to the community.