# How to unbind() all event handlers automatically upon adding change(...)?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I noticed a bug (in my code) that depended on the fact that each time I added *change(...)* to a component, the new functions was cumulatively added to the set of event handlers.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740213/automatically-unbind-event-handlers-in-jquery) was simple - I used *.unbind().change(...)* instead.

Now I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to add an event handler so that it removes all pre-existing ones?
2. Is it better to use *off()* (*die()* is apparently deprecated as of version 1.7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use off. It should work as you expected. Another nasty solution would be to set a new function to the event handler that does nothing (return false; or e.prevenDefault();)

Comment: Is *off()* preferred to *unbind()*? As for the setting the function to do nothing, I'm not sure if it works, because it seems that each time I execute *myControl.change(...)*, it adds the new function accumulating the stuff to do with the pre-existing ones.

Comment: Yes, from the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements." Unbind is not deprecated as far as I know but .on/.off is preferred